# service file returns "undefined" in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular 4 application,In this I am passing product name from (landingpage.component.ts)one component to Service file when the user clicked on the particular product.In service file I am getting the product image path from API by passing the product name.Then I am passing that image path to (my-car.component.ts)another component.But in my-cart component I got the path name as undefined.

component - service -component

Landingpage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CartdataService } from '../../services/cartdata.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landingpage',
  templateUrl: './landingpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landingpage.component.css']
})
export class LandingpageComponent {
  product_Name: any;
  ngOnInit() { }

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private router: Router{}

  getProductName(Pname: any) {
    this.CartdataService.get_Product_Path(Pname.textContent);
  }
}
```

cartdata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class CartdataService {

  public product_Path = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  cast_Product_Path = this.product_Path.asObservable();

  current_product : any;
  path :any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
get_Product_Path(pName : string)
  {
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/? 
    imageName=${this.current_product}`)
    .subscribe(data =>this.path = data[0]['Image_PATH_NAME'])
    this.product_Path.next(this.path);
  }
}
```

My-cart.component.ts

```
import { Component,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CartdataService} from '../../services/cartdata.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-cart',
  templateUrl: './my-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-cart.component.css'],
  outputs :['ChildEvent']
})

export class MyCartComponent  {

path:any;

constructor(private CartdataService :CartdataService,private router:Router,private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.CartdataService.cast_Product_Path.subscribe(product_Path=> this.path = product_Path);
}
}
```

In this component I am trying to get the path but receiving "undefined",I am new to angular4 ,please guide me to solve this .

Thanks.

Comment: Just rename cast_Product_Path with cast_Product_Path$ and try it will work. $ suffix (popularized by Cycle.js) is used to indicate that the variable is an Observable. And also Inject CartdataService in your AppModule as providers and do not inject it anywahere else, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `this.product_Path.next(this.path)` inside `subscribe` in your service

```
...
.subscribe(data => {
  this.path = data[0]['Image_PATH_NAME'])
  this.product_Path.next(this.path);
});
```

Comment: I need a suggestion from you ,This code is worked fine for me.After getting value from service file to my-cart component I set the path as the image path .But When I refresh the page the value get "Undefined ",How can I handle this ..?